# How to create a new document from the current document using Javascript and Lotusscript

Tags: javascript, lotusscript

I am trying to create a new document wherein some of the field values would come from the current document. Note that current document is not in edit mode.

There are three buttons in the current document:

**Edit Document**

```
//Validate inputs
myForm = window.document.forms[0]
myForm.Refresh.click()
myForm.Edit.click()
```

**Add Guest**

```
//Validate inputs
myForm = window.document.forms[0]
myForm.AddGuest.click()
```

**Close**

```
myForm = window.document.forms[0]
myForm.Close.click()
```

---

Once the Add Guest button is clicked, it must be able to access the lotusscript agent which can be found in another hidden button, "AddGuest".

```
@Command([ToolsRunMacro]; "AddGuests")
```

Once the Add Guest button's clicked, there must be a new form coming up but some of the field values (first name, last name, etc.) must retain and the form must be editable so I can save it as new document (not a response). Can anyone help me with the agent code to do that? Below is the code for my agent.

```
Sub Initialize
Dim session As NotesSession
Dim db As NotesDatabase
Dim currentdoc As NotesDocument
Dim newdoc As NotesDocument
Dim workspace As NotesUIWorkspace

Set session = New NotesSession
Set workspace = New NotesUIWorkspace
Set db = session.CurrentDatabase
Set currentdoc = workspace.Currentdocument.document
Set newdoc = New NotesDocument(db)
Call newDoc.Replaceitemvalue("FirstName", "")

Call workspace.EditDocument(newdoc,True)
End Sub
```

Upon trying to click the button, nothing's happening.

Comment: Hi, What's the target client ? Notes or Browser ?

Comment: Hi! Target client is web browser.

Comment: Ok. Then you're agent cannot use the UI Classes. Save the document first and then print the link to it in [ ] something like "[print https://[fqdn]/dbid/0/documentid?editdocument]", or have a look at the new and shiny xpages / java world....

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

Get current document

```
set currentDoc = workspace.CurrentDocument.Document
```

Create a new document

```
Set newDoc = new NotesDocument(db)
call newDoc.ReplaceItemValue("Form", "AddGuest")
```

Add values fra current document to new doc
    call newDoc.Replaceitemvalue("FirstName", currentDoc.FirstName)
    call newDoc.Replaceitemvalue("LastName", currentDoc.LastName)

Show the new document in edit mode

```
call workspace.Editdocument(newDoc, True)
```

Comment: Same form is being accessed, just saving as new document. Will the code,

call newDoc.ReplaceItemValue("Form", "AddGuest")

still be appropriate?

Comment: I can now see that you are using JavaScript. I this code running from the Notes client or a web browser?

Comment: Hi. It's running in a web browser.